# RUBY 2.0.0 How to run a file in irb, so that all its methods are parts of irb environment?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I know the command for this is: require file name
but I guess this command is for ruby 1.9.4 and I am using ruby 2.0.0
the exact message is.

```
$require start.rb  
LoadError: cannot load such file -- start.rb  
    from /home/aka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'  
    from /home/aka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'  
    from (irb):2  
    from /home/aka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:13:in `<main>'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no Ruby 1.9.4. What is the value of `$require`? In addition, the code is not valid Ruby.

Comment: @sawa I mean the older version to ruby 2.0.0.... I am least bothered about the exact older version name !!
it's just that this command wasn't working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside irb

```
>> require './start'
=> true
```

The file **start.rb** being in the same folder as you are, and the required file being in quotes, prefaced with the relative location `./` as shown.

This should work for you in Ruby from 1.8 on to 2.0 and beyond.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require), `require` will look for `start.rb` in the `$LOAD_PATH` since it does not resolve to an absolute path. In this case, the `LoadError` is telling you that `start.rb` is not in your `$LOAD_PATH`.

I am guessing that `start.rb` is in your current directory. You can use

```
>> require '/path/to/start.rb'
```

or

```
>> require './start.rb'
```

or

```
>> require './start'
```

Answer (score 0):

This saves you some typing:

```
$ irb -r ./start.rb
```